# C# console app (in a different project) calling async method in class library hangs

Tags: c#, asynchronous, dll

I created a class library that makes async calls to MS Graph API.  It works great from a console app that lives in the same project.  If a add a console app as a new project within the solution and call the async method, the call to Graph just hangs.  I figure it may be a deadlock, but I haven't been able to fix it (perhaps I need to re-think the architecture...?).  Here is the (scaled down) method in the dll (GraphMail):

```
//graphClient is an already initiated GraphServiceClient
    public async Task<string> GetMail()
    {
        var messages = await graphClient.Users[user]
            .MailFolders[folder]                
            .Messages                
            .Request()
            .Filter(filter)
            .Select(u => new {
                u.Id,
                u.SentDateTime,
                u.From,
                u.ToRecipients,
                u.Subject,
                u.Body
            })
            .GetAsync();

    return "I'm back";
}
```

and the call from the Program (each comment is an attempt):

```
        GraphMail grMail = new GraphMail();

        //var result = grMail().Result;
        //var result = bhMail.GetMail().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //var result = Task.Run(() => grMail()).Result;
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried `await`ing the result?

Comment: [Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: Adding await requires async on Main, which throws an error: 
Error CS5001 Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Comment: I tried adding "ConfigureAwait(false) " to .GetAsync() but that didn't fix it.  I'll try adding async to the caller

Answer (score 0):

Your examples seem to be missing the obvious one where you await the result.

Your console app should ensure it is using an async Task Main:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   GraphMail grMail = new GraphMail();

   var result = await grMail.GetMail();
}
```

Comment: Thanks.   This throws an error: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.  I'll try adding a helper...

Comment: I was able to change the Main method to "private static async Task Main(string[] args)" and make my call using var result = await bhMail.GetMail().  still no love. I've re-read "Don't Block on Async Code" but must be overlooking something. I need fresh eyes :)

Comment: If you debug into it, what do you see, where does it stop?

Comment: on this:  var messages = await graphClient.Users[user]
            .MailFolders[folder]                
            .Messages                
            .Request()
            .Filter(filter)
            .Select(u => new {
                u.Id,
                u.SentDateTime,
                u.From,
                u.ToRecipients,
                u.Subject,
                u.Body
            })
            .GetAsync();